# SharePoint particular group few users not able to login SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, login

In my SharePoint site I have a `mangers group`, `approver group` and `business users` group.

`Business users` group for some users they not able to login.

Same user if I had in `approver group` they able to login.

This is happening only for few users.

How to fix this issues?

What is the problem with `Business users group` only for few users?

[image]

Comment: What permissions are currently given to the 'Business users group'? Also, are you stating that only a subset of users within the 'Business users groups' is facing this issue? Or the whole group?

Comment: Business users group--- > Read - Minimal Access , and its not happening for whole group.Onlt for few users from Business users group.

Comment: do you have access to sharepoint logs? Try checking them, they'll provide you with information, why the login fail for those users.